# Open matlab figure on Java Swing button click

Tags: java, swing, matlab, figure

I would like to, if it is possible, to open MATLAB figure, generated in MATLAB function, on JButton click. (Maybe to add it to a JFrame or something like that.)

So far I done these steps:

1. in MATLAB: create m-file, add it to a java package project, build it with MATLAB Builder JA;
2. in Eclipse: create new project, import files, create GUI and on button click call matlab function to do all necessary calculation...and with setText write results in textFileds.

but how can I show figures on button click and is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

It would be simplier if you use the matlab GUI (which uses JButton). You can use [findjobj](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14317-findjobj-find-java-handles-of-matlab-graphic-objects)
to get the JButton object inside the matlab interface for the `uicontrol('Style','pushbutton')`.

But, if you don't want to do so, you could use JMI. This [article](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/jmi-java-to-matlab-interface/) gives you some information about it. His book may be very useful for you.